# Why do HttpUrlConnection (facebookSDK) fail when using 2g data connection?

Tags: android, facebook

I am trying to socialize my android app, starting with facebook, i successfully did a post on me/feeds with my WiFi connection...but when i use just 2g data connection  for the same code the result i get is either exception for "connection timeout" or sometimes  "Network is unreachable".

The problem happens in the Request class of the facebookSDk, where it uses the HttpUrlConnection to connect to fb.

```
connection.setDoOutput(true);

BufferedOutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
```

connection.getOutputStream() waits a bit and throws me sometimes SocketTimeoutException or at times a Network unreachable

And

1. yes i uses RequestAsyncTask
2. yes i checked the graph.facebbok.com url using the phones browser , with 2g connection,   it returns me an error json.
3. yes i tried the examples given in the facebookSDk, it also dont seem to work.
4. yes it absolutely works using WiFi connection

Since i mostly get the timeout exception i dont think its a problem with my connection, also in browser i am able to make the url return something.

I have searched across the stack for an answer , but nothing of this sort. so i wish someone could offer me a helping hand.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error `SocketTimeoutException` indicates that your connection is disconnected due to no response from server after certain period of time. Since 2G offers slow data transfer speeds, therefore I would suggest you to increase your time-out to some higher value. For testing purposes, perhaps double or triple the value.

Comment: i gave timeouts too...up to 30 seconds....still after 30 sec..it fails...but what confuses me is that it work like a piece of cake when in WiFi...or is it that i am not supposed to use it with 2g connection...?

Comment: WiFi connection is considered to be the fastest on mobile devices. Can you increase the timeout to 60 seconds and see any effects?

Comment: does it really wait for 60 seconds and then finally throws the exception or it occurs after few seconds?

Comment: it occurs after few seconds, the exception is still Connection timed out.

Comment: hmmm it doesn't look good. Try restarting your device or try fetching some random data from any other server (not facebook). If all still doesn't work then i believe your 2g connection seems very unstable or slow.

Comment: yes its dead slow. but y do i get instant response through the browser..?beats me...anyway i am thinking of informing the user with a "Weak Connection" message. as its said in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650129/how-to-debug-sockettimeoutexception